# Get root directory in ASP Classic application

Tags: asp-classic, path, directory

I have several relative paths in my ASP Classic application. I'd like to get a reference to the root directory of my particular application (since the root of the server is something different) for the purpose of setting paths.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way to do it using some server variables. Can anyone vouch for any possible bugs this way?

```
function getRoot()


pathinfo=Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")

Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "^(/\w*/).*"
' Pop up a message box for each match
getRoot = myRegExp.Replace (pathinfo, "$1")


end function
```

Comment: You had 1 problem, with the regex, you now have 2 ;)

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried

```
<%= Server.MapPath("/") %>
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `Request.ServerVariables("APPL_MD_PATH")` or `Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH")`.

Comment: `Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH")` worked for me. Thanks!